# Powerpoint changing one character's color in a chart's datalabel through COM in python

Tags: python-3.x, com, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint presentation where I have a chart where I want to change one charcter's colour in a datalabel.
[image: Here is an example of what I want to achieve. The triangle to be coloured red] In VBA I can do this with

```
ChartObject.SeriesCollection(SeriesCounter).Points(PointCounter).DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 2).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ColourSigLower
```

However, when I try to do the same via Python 3 COM I get the following error

```
com_error: (-2147352559, 'Does not support a collection.', None, None)
```

Here is a full code snippet of what I try to do:

```
pythoncom.CoInitialize()
ppt_instance = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch('PowerPoint.Application')
#open the powerpoint presentation headless in background
read_only = True
has_title = False
window    = False

myCompath=str(path.parent / 'Report' /  'test.pptx')
myCOMpath_output=str(path.parent / 'Report' /  'Output_test.pptx')
prsCOM = ppt_instance.Presentations.open(myCompath,has_title,window)

def RGB(R,G,B):
 return B*256*256+G*256+R

chart_obj=prsCOM.Slides("BFDOT").Shapes("TOM").Chart

aaamy = chart_obj.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1).DataLabel.Text
chart_obj.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1).DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text= aaamy + " " + chr(9660)
###Below line is where it breaks
chart_obj.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1).DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1,2).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(245, 165, 150) #Here is where it breaks
prsCOM.SaveAs(myCOMpath_output)
prsCOM.Close
prsCOM.Application.Quit()
pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
```

Do you have ideas how can I accomplish this?
I have tried early and late binding but doesn't help.

Comment: I'm not very fond of Python and I could not test anything here. Just a question: Are you trying to convert The RGB value to decimal? If so, first off, that is not the correct formula. Have a look [here](https://excelatfinance.com/xlf/xlf-colors-1.php), section 3. Second, one would guess `Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB` is expecting a RGB value, so why do you want to convert it to decimal in the first place. Couldn't you use the decimal color values directly like `Font.Color = 9872885` instead?

Comment: @horst Thanks for having a look! The function uses the same formula as the link you gave.  I have tested it numerous times and it is working correctly.  I probably can use Font.Color but then I wouldn't know what value to put. (I have a person that is telling me the RGB value).

Comment: `Red * 256 ^ 0 + Green * 256 ^ 1 + Blue * 256 ^ 2` is not the same formula as `return B*256*256+G*256+R` from your code. But anyway, maybe try something like this: `.Font.Color.RGB = VBA.RGB(245, 165, 150)`

Comment: I don't understand why it is not the same? Can you elaborate? Blue * 256 ^ 2 is equal to B*256*256 ?