# Excel to PowerPoint VBA Loop

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Fist of all, I'm not good with VBA, and to be honest I don't know how to go about on this problem.

**The Situation**

I have a database as shown below with multiple entries (*currently only 2, but there will be more as soon as the students will progress with there work*). I want to be able to filter the database and then depending on the selection put the information in a PowerPoint Slide.

[image]

I created (*with a lot of youtube videos*) a script that will copy the relevant information from one line onto a PowerPoint presentation into the defined fields.

**Problem**

I have absolutely no idea how to loop that code in order to bring only the filtered Information onto the PowerPoint. Can someone guide me on how to go about it?

```
Sub XLS_to_PPT()
    Dim pptPres As Presentation
    Dim strPfad As String
    Dim strPOTX As String
    Dim pptApp As Object
        
    strPfad = "C:XXX"
    strPOTX = "PPT_Template.pptx"
        
    Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application
        
    pptVorlage = strPfad & strPOTX
        
    pptApp.Presentations.Open Filename:=pptVorlage, untitled:=msoTrue
        
    Set pptPres = pptApp.ActivePresentation
        
    pptPres.Slides(1).Duplicate
    pptPres.Slides(1).Select
    pptPres.Slides(1).Shapes("Header").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = Worksheets("PPT_Creation").Cells(5, 5).Value
    pptPres.Slides(1).Shapes("ClientChanlenge").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = Worksheets("PPT_Creation").Cells(5, 9).Value
    pptPres.Slides(1).Shapes("HowWeHelped").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = Worksheets("PPT_Creation").Cells(5, 10).Value
        
    pptPres.SaveAs strPfad & ("New_Request")
        
    pptPres.Close
        
    Set pptPres = Nothing
    Set pptApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plan is to create a new slide for each visible row in the table, i presume.
so you could loop through the table like this:

```
For Each tableRow In Sheets("NameOfYourSheet").ListObjects("NameOfYourTable").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows
    set newSlide = pptPres.Slides(1).Duplicate
    newSlide.Shapes("Header").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = tableRow.Columns(5).Value
    newSlide.Shapes("ClientChanlenge").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = tableRow.Columns(9).Value
    newSlide.Shapes("HowWeHelped").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = tableRow.Columns(10).Value
Next tableRow
```

Basically we go through each row in the table, duplicate slide(1), use that new slide object to populate the shapes inside by the given column numbers.
`SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` takes care of ignoring the filtered out rows.

Answer (score 1):

try looking into [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849177/easiest-way-to-loop-through-a-filtered-list-with-vba)

There it is described how to loop through a filtered list.  There is information there how to get the address of the cell in you are looping through and so on

edit: after I got reprimanded I am posting full solution. Hope it works.
edit2: now made it so it works for arbitrary number of slides

```
Sub XLS_to_PPT()

Dim pptPres As Presentation
Dim strPfad As String
Dim strPOTX As String
Dim pptApp As Object

    
    strPfad = "C:XXX"
    strPOTX = "PPT_Template.pptx"
    
    Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    
    
    pptVorlage = strPfad & strPOTX
    
    pptApp.Presentations.Open Filename:=pptVorlage, untitled:=msoTrue
    
    
    Set pptPres = pptApp.ActivePresentation
    'below if set the range to 500 but you may want to increase /decrease that number depending on how many entries you expecty
    Set rng = Range("A5:A500")
    
  For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        
    set mynewslide=pptPres.Slides(1).Duplicate
    
    
    ' I do not think you need below line
    'pptPres.Slides(1).Select
    
    mynewslide.Shapes("Header").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = Worksheets("PPT_Creation").Cells(cl.row, 5).Value
    mynewslide.Shapes("ClientChanlenge").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = Worksheets("PPT_Creation").Cells(cl.row, 9).Value
    mynewslide.Shapes("HowWeHelped").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = Worksheets("PPT_Creation").Cells(cl.row, 10).Value
    
        
    Next cl
  
    pptPres.SaveAs strPfad & ("New_Request")
     
    pptPres.Close
    
    Set pptPres = Nothing
    Set pptApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: edited my answer so it provides a full solution.  Will mark similar posts in future as duplicates or will provide my solutions as suggested. THanks

Comment: When a Slide(1) is duplicated, the duplicate will be Slide(2). Not Slides.Count, like you suggest. Which could be any number, depending on the number of slides in the presentation. So on every loop you overwrite the last Slide instead of the newly created one.

Comment: yes you are right. I just assumed the presentation has 1 slide.  I will further edit my answer

Comment: Even if the presentation only had 1 slide there would be the same problem starting with the second iteration of the loop.

Comment: uh you are again right of course. The edited solution should work now that i do it similarly to how you do it.  :)

Comment: @horst you seems experienced with VBA. Any idea on this question that I posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64371361/powerpoint-changing-one-characters-color-in-a-charts-datalabel-through-com-in